# Solve a system of non linear equation with a bisection method

Tags: equation-solving

I have a nonlinear system of equation to solve and I want to use a bisection method because a classical `FindRoot` seems not working easily.

Here is my equation:

```
E1 = 0.53*10^9;
k1 = 0.269*10^(-6);
K1 = 0.5;
α1 = 30*10^(-6);
ν1 = 0.25;
μ1 = E1/(2 (1 + ν1));

E2 = 125*10^9;
k2 = 12.98*10^(-6);
K2 = 54;
α2 = 12*10^(-6);
ν2 = 0.25;
μ2 = E2/(2 (1 + ν2));
k = k1/k2;
K = K1/K2;
α = (α1 (1 + ν1))/(α2 (1 + ν2));
f = 0.4;
a = 5*10^(-3);

ξ1[c1_] := Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])];
ξ2[c2_] := Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c2)^2])];
η1[c1_] := - Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])];
η2[c2_] := -Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + c2^2])];
H1sym[A_] := 
  2*μ1*μ2*
   k2*α2 (1 + ν2)/(K2 (μ2 (1 - ν1) (A Sech[A]^2 + 
           Tanh[A]) + μ1 (1 - ν2) Tanh[A]^2));

H2sym[A_] := 
  4*μ1*μ2*
   k2*α2 (1 + ν2)/(K2 (μ2 (1 - 2 ν1) (A Sech[A]^2 +
            Tanh[A]) - μ1 (1 - 2 ν2) Tanh[
          A] + μ1 A Sech[A]^2));

Hsym[A_] := H1sym[A]/H2sym[A]

I1[c2_, A_] := (ξ2[c2] Sinh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - η2[c2] Sin[
       2 A η2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] + Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
I2[c2_, A_] := (ξ2[c2] Sin[2 A η2[c2]] + η2[c2] Sinh[
       2 A ξ2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] + Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
I3[c1_, A_] := (α/ξ1[c1]) (A Sech[A]^2 + Tanh[A]);
I4[c2_, A_] := (Tanh[A]/(ξ2[c2] η2[c2]) ) I2[c2, A];
J3[c1_, A_] := (α η1[
       c1]/(ξ1[c1] (ξ1[c1] + 1))) (A Sech[A]^2 + Tanh[A]);
J4[c2_, A_] := (Tanh[
      A]/(ξ2[c2] η2[c2]) ) (ξ2[c2] Sinh[
        2 A ξ2[c2]] - η2[c2] Sin[2 A η2[c2]] - 
      Tanh[A] (Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] + Cos[2 A η2[c2]]))/(Cosh[
       2 A ξ2[c2]] + Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
V[c1_, c2_] := c1 - c2;

equation68[c1_, V_, A_] := 
  K ξ1[c1] + I1[c1 - V, A] + 
    f Hsym[A] (K η1[c1] + 
       I2[c1 - V, A]) - (f H1sym[A]/2 ) (I3[c1, A] + I4[c1 - V, A])*
     c1 - V == 0;   

equation69[c1_, V_, A_] := 
  K η1[c1] + I2[c1 - V, A] - 
    f Hsym[A] (k ξ1[c1] + 
       I1[c1 - V, A]) + (f H1sym[A]/2 ) (J3[c1, A] + J4[c1 - V, A])*
     V == 0;
```

I have equation68 and equation 69 to solve in fonction of A and I know that V=c1-c2
In order to solve this system, I want to use this method:
-For each A between 1,5 and 7, with a step 0.1
-I fix an initial value of V (V=10^4 for exemple)
-I solve equation68 in order to find c1

- I test if equation69==0. If yes, I have the good value of V, else, I change V,  with the same way the a classical bisection method.

I m not sure how create this Algorithm, can someone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try using [`ResourceFunction["BisectionMethodFindRoot"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BisectionMethodFindRoot)

Comment: You have 3 unknowns and 2 equations?

Comment: I have 4 unknows (A, c1, c2, V) and 3 equations (equation76, equation77 and V=c1-c2).
And I want to solve this system for each and between 2 and 6 for example.
So with this condition, I have 3 unknowns for 3 equations

Comment: for each A between 2 and 6*